# Please explain this theorem to a physics student

Tags: integration, measure-theory

I asked a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2989782/physics-electric-field) last day. The answer seems to be too esoteric for me to understand. Please explain so that a physics student like me can understand.

> **Let $(X,\mu)$ be a measures set, let $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a measurable function and let $g:Y\rightarrow X$ be  change of variables, then** 
>   \begin{align}
> \int_{X} |f\circ g|\, \mathrm d \mu< +\infty \quad\Leftrightarrow\quad \int_{Y} |f|\,g\#\mathrm d \mu < +\infty
> \tag1
> \end{align}

This theorem is valid in a **very wide** generality : the change of variable  $g$ do not need to be continuous or bijective and it includes all change of variable you might encounter. I wrote $\phi \# \mathrm d \mu$ for the image measure. For instance, let $X=\mathbb R^3$ and $Y= [0,2\pi]\times [0,\pi]\times \mathbb R_ +^*$, let 
$$ g : \begin{matrix}Y&\rightarrow &X \\ (\theta,\phi,r)&\mapsto& (r\cos(\theta)\cos(\phi),r\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi),r\sin(\phi))\end{matrix}$$ 
You recognize your spherical change of variable and 
$$\mathrm d\mu = \mathrm d x\mathrm dy \mathrm d z \quad\quad \quad g\#\mathrm d \mu = r^2\sin(\phi)\mathrm d \theta \mathrm d \phi \mathrm d r$$
here $f=\rho \hat r$.

**Please write equation (1) in the language of elementary multivariable calculus**

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is just a way of stating the change of variable theorem for integrals over several variables.

Comment: $|f\circ g|:Y\to\mathbb R$ (not $X\to\mathbb R$) so integral $\int_X|f\circ g|d\mu$ makes no sense.

Comment: Please refer to the answer to my last question.

Comment: There are some issues with this expression as drhab mentions, but it is simply stating that a function which is absolutely integrable in one coordinate system will be absolutely integrable in any coordinate system.

Comment: @AlexanderJ93: Can you please help me understand the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2989782/physics-electric-field?noredirect=1&lq=1) to my last question?

Comment: How much measure theory do you know?

Comment: I have only heard about it. Don't even know it's abc basics.